# Angular | ChartJs Annotation Plugin - Link the position of a line to the mouse

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I try to create a crosshair with the annotation plugin, I manage to modify the value of my line but it does not update on the chart.

Here is an overview of my chart options :

```js
public financialChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
  plugins: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: {
        line1: {
          id: 'line1',
          type: 'line',
          borderColor: 'black',
          borderWidth: 3,
          scaleID: 'y',
          value: 30
        }
      }
    },
  },
  onHover: (e: any) => {
    e.native.target.style.cursor = 'crosshair';
    this.crosshair(e)
  },
  onLeave: function (e: any) {
    e.native.target.style.cursor = 'default';
  }
}
```

And here is my crosshair function :

```js
crosshair(e: any) {
  //@ts-ignore
  this.chart!.options!.plugins!.annotation!.annotations!["line1"].value = e.chart.scales.y.getValueForPixel(e.y)
  //@ts-ignore
  console.log(this.chart!.options!.plugins!.annotation!.annotations!["line1"].value)
  this.chart?.update()
}
```

The console.log returns me the desired value but nothing changes on the chart.

Please let me know if there are better ways to create both vertical and horizontal crosshair.

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js has a plugin called [`chartjs-plugin-crosshair`](https://chartjs-plugin-crosshair.netlify.app/samples/) maybe that will satisfy your requirements, do check it out!

[reference stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-crosshair-tryout)

Comment: The problem with this plugin is that it does not offer horizontal crosshair